# R how to import bulk txt files named after the same pattern and extract rows with the same name from all files

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am so a beginner...
I have 36 txt files as shown in the screenshot below
[image: file list]
In each file, I have 23154 rows with the same names. However, the column numbers and names are different among the files.
My purpose is to extract several specific rows from each paper and merge them together into a new data frame. Columns are grouped by row names.

One of the file looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIyLc.jpg)

So row names are gene ID and column names actually annotated of the stage of the cells where the genes measured from. Each file, contains one or two stages, and each stage has approximate 20 replicates.

For example, I want to pick Phf20 and Kat8. In the final file, I want each column represents the mean counts of each stage, and sorted by each gene. Attached below is what I expected it to look like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0WNH.png)

Can anyone help? Please...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you share some more details about the data that you have? How do the files look? Can you share first few rows of couple of files along with their column names? Which specific rows do you want to extract? How will the final output look?

Comment: Hi Ronak! Thanks for your reply! I am editing to the question according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is roughly how I would go about this (note I couldn't test this code since I don't have your data):

1. Create a list of your files:

```
    myfiles<-list.files(yourfilepath)
```

2. Loop over this list to read the txt files and extract the relevant info:

```
    myrows<-c(1,2,3) #1,2,3 are the rows of interest
    
    for(i in seq_along(myfiles)){
      
      #you can also use read.table, depends how are your files delimited:
      mydata<-read.delim(myfiles[i]) 
      
      #select rows:
      mydata<-mydata[myrows,] 
      
      if(i == 1){
        finaldata<-mydata
      }else{
        #combine data frames by colums:
        finaldata<-cbind(finaldata, mydata) 
      }
      
      rm(mydata)
      
    }
```

Comment: Hi bricx, Thanks for your help! I am trying to test your codes. Thanks a lot!